# ComboBox not updating with Itemsource change

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

My class Looks like this:

```vb
Public Class CoursesLib
    Public CoursesOfferedMAIN As New Dictionary(Of String, Category)
    Public Class Category
        Private _CategoryName As String
        Private _Deleted As Boolean
        Public Courses As New Dictionary(Of String, Course)
        Public Function Contains(ByVal CourseName As String)
            For Each k As Course In Courses.Values
                If k.CourseName = CourseName Then
                    Return True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
            Return False
        End Function
    End Class
    Public Class Course
        Private _CategoryName As String
        Private _CourseID As String
        Private _CourseName As String
        Private _Deleted As Boolean
        Public Sems As New Dictionary(Of String, Sem)
        End Sub
        Public Function Contains(ByVal find As String)
            For Each k As Sem In Sems.Values
                If k.SemName = find Then
                    Return True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
            Return False
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

Following is the code i used for xaml in my wpf:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="Categories" Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <ComboBox Height="30" Name="CourseCategoryComboBox1"  Width="120">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding CategoryName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
            <Button Name="AddNewCourseCategoryButton" Background="Transparent" Content="Add New" Foreground="#FF0994EB"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="NewCategorySubmitStackPanel">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Height="30" Name="NewCourseCategoryTextBox1"  Width="120" MaxLength="25"/>
            <Button Name="SubmitNewCourseCategoryButton" Background="Transparent" Content="+" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF0994EB" FontWeight="Heavy"   BorderBrush="Transparent" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="CourseListStackPanel" >
            <TextBlock Text="Course" Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <ComboBox Height="30" Name="CourseslistComboBox1" Width="120">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding CourseName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
            <Button Name="NewCourseButton" Background="Transparent" Content="Add New" Foreground="#FF0994EB"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="NewCourseeSubmitStackPanel">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Height="24" Name="NewCourseeTextBox1"  Width="120" MaxLength="25"/>
            <Button Name="SubmitNewCourseButton" Background="Transparent" Content="+" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF0994EB" FontWeight="Heavy"   BorderBrush="Transparent" />
        </StackPanel>
```

The problem is when the add a new course to the collection, the combox is not updating, but when i restart the app, it gets added, it is not getting inserted when I complete the insert statement.  Following is the code i use. Inserting and Updating the control:

```vb
If Not NewCourseeTextBox1.Text = "" Then
        If Globals.Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN(CType(CourseCategoryComboBox1.SelectedItem, WorkMateLib.CoursesLib.Category).CategoryName).Contains(NewCourseeTextBox1.Text) = False Then
            Dim c As New WorkMateLib.CoursesLib.Course
            c.Category = CType(CourseCategoryComboBox1.SelectedItem, WorkMateLib.CoursesLib.Category).CategoryName
            c.CourseID = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
            c.CourseName = NewCourseeTextBox1.Text
            c.Deleted = False
            Dim serv As New ServiceCourses.WCFCoursesClient
            Dim ex As String
            ex = serv.AddCourse(c)
            If ex = "1" Then
                NewCourseeTextBox1.Text = ""
                NewCourseeSubmitStackPanel.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
                Globals.Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN(c.Category).Courses.Add(c.CourseID, c)
                CourseslistComboBox1.ItemsSource = Globals.Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN(c.Category).Courses.Values
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(ex)
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Thank you.

Comment: please format your code in a code block and specify the language tag to get proper syntax coloring!

Comment: Where do you bind/set the `ItemsSource` ?

Comment: @Zebi I did not use any bind, I just directly assign the source.

Comment: @Davide Piras, I did add as code, but it is not showing, please tell me, in order to get recognised as code we just need to add 4 spaces before every line right, please correct me if I am wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few methods and of them all following worked and is the easiest one as for me:

The trick is to change the ItemSource Property to nothing first and then assigning the list or any other data source, this way, the Items are getting displayed right away without any problem.
Example:

Thank you for your time and help.

```
SubjectlistComboBox1.ItemsSource = Nothing
                        SubjectlistComboBox1.ItemsSource = Globals.Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN(c.Category).Courses(c.CourseID).Sems(c.SemID).Subjects.Values
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary does not provide add, remove notification use ObservableCollection(Of T).

Comment: What you said might be right, but I used the Itemsource again, hence the new source must be taken and updated.

Comment: I did not use any binding, I directly assigned the dictionary values.

Comment: Direct assignment is VB 6.0 style I would advice you to use binding when it comes to wpf. If not you are still better off with an observable collection for dependency properties.

Comment: Thanks @anivas, I would still like to view few more options other than binding, It is also a good option, but I want to check for more alternatives or to know why it is not updating.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually changing the `ItemsSource`.  This line:

```
CourseslistComboBox1.ItemsSource = Globals.Courses.CoursesOfferedMAIN(c.Category).Courses.Values
```

is setting the `ItemsSource` to the value that it is already assigned to:  the `Values` property of the `CoursesOfferedMAIN` dictionary.  Since you haven't changed the value, the combo box doesn't do anything.

It's not a very good idea to use a dictionary's `Values` property as the `ItemsSource` anyway.  Dictionaries don't maintain their values in a predictable order, and so they'll be appearing in an essentially random order in your UI.

You probably want to create a `CollectionView` of the `Values`.  WPF's `CollectionViewSource` object is what you'd use to do this.  (See [Bea Stollnitz's article](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387) for a very good introduction to why `CollectionViewSource` is needed and how it works.)  Once the `CollectionView` exists, you simply call `Refresh` on it every time you modify the collection that it's based on, and the view takes care of sorting/filtering and notifying the UI.

Comment: Collectionview is a good point to use then the data is limited into 1 or two classes I mean Hierarchy, however, in this case, I have many types and also they are like tree hierarchy, hence as per my, I think managing the collectionview gets difficult for me.  Thank you @Robert Rossney  . It is a very informative post and I will use this information when situation permits.

Comment: Rossney, sorry as to that, I have added only part of the code because most of the other classes are similar but the hierarchy is to about 5 level depth hence it is a bit big code to post.